# How do I change my SIM pin?

Tags: 8.1, settings

I just got a new SIM card with a default pin code. I assumed I could change this in Settings - Mobile+SIM - SIM Settings, but it's not possible there. How can I change this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found my answer on the Microsoft help page. For some reason they put this functionality in the Settings of the Phone app:

- Go to the Phone app, tap ... and select Settings.
- tap change SIM pin and follow instructions.

Source: [How do I change PIN code on my Lumia phone?](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA137530)

Comment: The link is broken by now.